# Aframe animation component errors on round (which I disabled)

Tags: aframe

I'm pretty sure this was working in previous version of Aframe, but can't be sure. However I get a strange error when I try and animate the position on a component with:

```
const positionAnimation = {
  property:     'position',
  from:         this._threeElement.position,
  to:           (reversed) ? this._initialPosition : this._targetPosition,
  dur:          2000,
  round:        false,
  easing:       'easeInOutCubic',
  startEvents:  ['---non-existent-event---'], //Avoid auto-play of the animation
}

 //Set the animation on the element
this.el.setAttribute('animation__position', positionAnimation)
```

It seems to be related to the position property (if I remove this no error but it doesn't animate)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
    at round (aframe-master.js:8445)
    at I (anime.min.js:13)
    at ba (anime.min.js:18)
    at anime.min.js:19
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at da (anime.min.js:19)
    at anime.min.js:20
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at anime.min.js:20
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at ea (anime.min.js:20)
    at fa (anime.min.js:21)
    at q (anime.min.js:24)
    at NewComponent.createAndStartAnimation (index.js:164)
    at NewComponent.update (index.js:122)
    at NewComponent.updateProperties (aframe-master.js:72452)
    at NewComponent.module.exports.Component (aframe-master.js:72222)
    at new NewComponent (aframe-master.js:72646)
    at HTMLElement.value (aframe-master.js:71059)
    at HTMLElement.value (aframe-master.js:71215)
    at HTMLElement.value (aframe-master.js:71386)
    at NewComponent.tweenHotspotToCamera (zoom-front-camera.js:127)
```

EDIT the problem is in the 'to' attribute (if I remove it I get no error but no animation)

There is data in there

```
from:Vector3
x:8.743012486033315
y:1.7184335476624883
z:-5.017845407952605
__proto__
:
Object
property
:
"position"
startEvents
:
["---non-existent-event---"]
to
:
Vector3
x:8.26445236188911
y:0.33004119004908694
z:-11.007824476509064
```

This is animation component v 4.2.0 and Aframe 0.8.2

EDIT - This did work in Aframe 0.5

Have a look at this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/qzox15w5/1/

This is working as expected, however if I upgrade AFRAME I get the error mentioned before.

https://jsfiddle.net/jpvsrnq1/1/

I've tried using AFRAME.utils.clone the Vector however this is having undesired results.

Comment: when, and how are you setting _initialPosition, _targetPosition, _threeElement ? it seems you're doing it after setting the animation component, because it seems to be working https://jsfiddle.net/jp2h8oy7/

Comment: They are set in a previous function, but they are all there I can console log them. They're 0 0 0 at the moment anyway.